# Вращение текста вокруг оси Y

Tags: css, html5, css3, svg, 3d

В последние несколько дней я немного занимался свойством `CSS transform`, и я хочу найти способ для отображения переспективы, похожее на это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С `Boxes` - все обычные прямоугольные `Boxes`. Я просто не знаю с чего начать.

Мой код:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.skewed {
  margin: -1px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(45deg);
}
.skewed > img {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale") blur(3px);
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.skewed:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image001.jpg">
</div>
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image002.jpg">
</div>
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image003.jpg">
</div>
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image004.jpg">
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Rotate text on th Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39878213/7394871) от участника  [@TheLexoPlexx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5207711/thelexoplexx).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878213/rotate-text-on-th-y-axis/39878486#39878486

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это довольно просто с [CSS 3D-transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Вы можете вращать каждый элемент по оси `Y` с помощью `Transform:rotateY(xdeg);`

Здесь пример:

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 7em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(30deg);
  background: teal;
}
div:nth-child(2n) {
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-30deg);
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что вам нужно будет добавить префиксы для поддержки браузера. Смотрите [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) для получения дополнительной информации

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39878486/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>